# How to calculate $\langle0|S(b) S(b) |0\rangle $ where $S(b)$ is the squeeze operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hilbert-space, quantum-optics

[image]

How to calculate $\langle0|S(b) S(b) |0\rangle $ where $S(b)$ is the squeeze operator

Comment: Please [use mathjax](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) instead of posting an image of math.

Comment: Required [reading](https://journals.aps.org/prd/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevD.29.1107).

Answer (score 2):

The usual sqeezing opertor is 
$$
S(z) \equiv  \exp\{   {\textstyle \frac12}( z {a^\dagger}^2-  z^*a^2)\}, \quad z= e^{\theta} |z| \\
= \exp\{ {\textstyle \frac12}  e^{i\theta} \tanh |z|   {a^\dagger}^2\}\exp\{ - \ln \cosh |z| (a^\dagger a+\textstyle \frac12)\}  \exp\{-  {\textstyle \frac12}  e^{-i\theta} \tanh |z|{a}^2\}
$$

If you paramtrize this as
$$
\hat S(\alpha)
=\exp\{{\textstyle \frac 12} \alpha {a^\dagger}^2\}\exp\{-i \omega (a^\dagger a +{\textstyle \frac 12})\}\exp\{- {\textstyle \frac 12} \alpha^* a^2\},
$$

you can use 
$$
\hat S(\alpha_2) \hat S(\alpha_1)= \hat S(\alpha_3) \exp\{i\chi(\alpha_1,\alpha_2) (a^\dagger a +{\textstyle \frac 12})\}
$$
where
$$ 
\alpha_3= \frac{\alpha_1+\alpha_2}{1+\alpha_1\alpha_2^*}, \quad \exp\{2i\chi\}= \frac{1+\alpha_1^*\alpha_2}{1+\alpha_1\alpha_2^* }
$$
to evaluate your expression.

I should probably add that proving these formulae requires a bit of ingenuity. The basic idea is that $a^2$ $a^\dagger a +1/2$ and $(a^\dagger)^2$ generate the Lie algebra Sp$(2, \mathbb R)$ and this algebra and the group obtained by exponentiating has a faithful but non unitary representation as two-by-two matrices. You map the squeeze operators  to matrices, establish the identity there, and them map back to squeeze operators.